# "Invalid \x escape" while creating a backup using sftp

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I took this code from a youtube video and attempted to edit it to help me
back up a folder on my laptop using `sftp`, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Invalid\x escape.
```

What can be causing this issue?

Here is my code:

```
import pysftp as sftp

def sftpExample():
    try:
        s = sftp.Connection(host='192.168.91.151',username='test',password='password')
        remotepath='/home/baar/test'
        localpath='C:\Users\xps\Desktop\testme'
        s.put(localpath,remotepath)

        s.close()#closes the connection
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)


sftpExample()
```

Comment: Try using `localpath = r'C:\Users\xps\Desktop\testme'`

Comment: Thank you Maximus it worked. What does the r do?

Comment: it makes it a raw string, which means the backslash characters are interpreted as-is (and not as escape characters). It is equivalent to replacing all backslashes with a double backslash.